# Verilog two dimensional array syntax

Tags: debugging, verilog, bit

I would like to instantiate an array of registers, and declare them all according to a certain function. This is for a multiplier block that I'm hoping to construct.

The code I'm working with is below, but this is the line that the compiler does not appreciate:

```
q[i][7:0] = {8{a[i]}} & b[7:0];
```

As the code is written out, I hope to make the registers q[0],q[1],....q[7] all store the 8-bit value define by the RHS above. Can anyone tell me what would be the proper way to do this?

Entire code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module multiplier_2(
    input [7:0] A,
    input [7:0] B,
    output reg [15:0] P,
    input start,
    output stop
    );

reg [7:0] q[7:0];
reg P = 0;
//create 8 bit vectors q[i]
genvar i;
generate 
for (i = 0; i < 8;i = i+1) 
begin: loop
    q[i][7:0] = {8{a[i]}} & b[7:0];
end
endgenerate

always @ (*)
begin
    if (start == 1'b1)
    begin
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i+1)
        begin
            P = P + (q[i] << i);
        end
    end
end

endmodule
```

---

EDIT: this code also doesn't work:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module multiplier_2(
    input [7:0] a,
    input [7:0] b,
    output reg [15:0] P = 16'd0,
    input start,
    output stop
    );

reg [7:0] q[7:0];
//create 8 bit vectors q[i]
genvar i;
generate 
always begin
    for (i = 0; i < 8;i = i+1) 
    begin: loop
        q[i] = {8{a[i]}} & b[7:0];
    end
end
endgenerate

always @ (*)
begin
    stop = 1'b0;
    if (start == 1'b1)
    begin
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i = i+1)
        begin
            P = P + (q[i] << i);
        end
    end
    stop = 1'b1;
end

endmodule
```

Error message:

*"Line 16: Procedural assignment to a non-register i is not permitted, left-hand side should be reg/integer/time/genvar"*

Comment: `q[0][7:0] = {8{a[0]}} & b[7:0];` would not be valid verilog. It needs an `assign` for a wire type or inside an `always` for a reg type.

Comment: if I put it inside "initial" , it still does not accept it. Same goes with always. Edit on my op also has a code that does not work.

Comment: Can anyone give insight as to why I was downvoted, so I can improve in the future?

Comment: It was not me, therefore can only guess, that there is a lot of code posted for the issue and you could have reduced it further. 1 down vote is not too bad though.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think this require a generate statement. A standard for loop will work:

```
reg [7:0] q [0:7];
integer i;
always @* begin
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i=i+1) begin: loop
      q[i] = {8{a[i]}} & b[7:0];
  end
end
```

Beware of what hardware you are implying though. For loops like generate statements imply parallel hardware.

NB: it is more common to list memories with the depth from 0 to x ie: `reg [7:0] q [0:7];`

Answer (score 1):

You've got all sorts of issues here. First off, you're getting confused about what a `generate` statement is, and what you're trying to generate. Are you (1) trying to generate a single `always` block, which must contain sequential/procedural code, or are you (2) trying to generate/replicate 8 continuous assignments?

You're presumably not doing (1), since there's no point in generating a single `always` block; the `generate` is redundant. That leaves (2). So, get rid of the `always begin` after the `generate`. The `i` in your loop is now the 'genvar', or generation variable, and you're replicating 8 assignments; so far, so good. Get rid of the `begin:loop` and `end`; you're replicating a single statement, so they're pointless verbiage.

Next problem: the generate loop is now creating *concurrent*, or *parallel*, statements; in Verilog-speak, they're module-level statements. They means that they must be *continuous* assignments, ie they must have an `assign` in front of them, and not just ordinary procedural assignments, as you've written them. That also means that `q` must be declared as a `wire`, and not a `reg`. There's no good reason for this; it's just how Verilog is.

You now have a second `always` block, which is a concurrent (module-level) statement, which must contain sequential/procedural code. The `i` you're referring to in this block is the original `genvar`, which doesn't work. A `genvar` can only be used in specific generation-related circumstances; this isn't inside a `generate`, and you need an ordinary variable here as your index. you can do this by naming your outer `begin`/`end`, and declaring a variable inside it, or any other way. You'll now find out that you're creating a procedural assignment to net `stop`; this is illegal, so change `stop`'s declaration to a reg. This should be enough to get your code to compile.

BTW, `@(*)` is verbose and unnecessary, and has historically confused at least one tool. `@*` is more concise.

You've got other issues. Your second `always` contains a loop. It looks like it might be logically correct, but your synthesiser has to unroll this, and carry out 8 additions, and set `stop`. This isn't going to work in real life. Think about making these additions concurrent and putting them in a `generate`, or creating a clocked pipeline, and some more robust (clocked) way of creating `stop`.

Comment: Yes, I'm confused about what a generate does. I read that it is works in pre-compile time, so I thought that assigning the necessary registers might be included, but now I see that I'm getting things mixed up. 
Why wouldn't the second loop work in real life?

Comment: @triplebig you have `stop = 1'b0;` `stop = 1'b1;` In the same combinatorial statement. Combinatorial statements ideally simulate in 0 time. so having a signal which changes between 2 values during 1 run of the block is not going to work.